# Rocky planet height maps

Tags: planets, worldbuilding-resources, map-making

anybody know where to find real height maps/bump maps of all the rocky planets and moons large enough to colonize in our solar system? Building 3D models and i want to terraform oceans forests and cities on the planets based on the bump maps

Comment: I apologize, but this isn't a worldbuilding question, so it's inevitably going to be closed.  Our focus is dealing with the rules governing fictional worlds.  If NASA doesn't have the data you're looking for, then you might try our sister sites Astronomy.SE and Space Exploration.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to either Astronomy.SE or Space Exploration.SE.

Comment: surely, the word you are looking for is "topographic" not "bump maps" :)

Comment: Also try the US geological society. at the very least, they seem to have some topographic maps of mars. see this 2MB pdf file-link https://pubs.usgs.gov/imap/i2782/i2782_sh1.pdf